# Access pandas DataFrame attributes inside chained methods

Tags: pandas, dataframe, attributes, method-chaining

Good afternoon,

I have a few .csv files to be transformed into pandas DataFrames. Although they contain the same type of data in the same columns, they have different column names. I am trying to do all the small transformations on the fly to be able to concatenate the DataFrames all at once. The problem I am having is that as far as I know there is not way to access the attributes of the DataFrame "on the fry", first you assign it to a variable and then access the data. In the following way:

```
df = pd.read_csv("my_csv.csv")
df = df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns, [my_columns])))
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows a way to do something like the following:

```
(pd.read_csv("my_csv.csv")
    .rename(columns=dict(zip(SELF.columns, [my_columns])))
)
```

where `SELF` references the DataFrame that has been just created.

So far I have tried unsuccessfully to use `lambda` functions as I know they can be used to subset the DataFrame by conditions set on the just created object like `[lambda x: x.ColumnA > 20]`

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

I was able to do what I was looking for with the help of `.pipe()` I did the following:

```
def rename_columns(self, columns):
    return self.rename(columns=dict(zip(self.columns, columns)))

(pd.DataFrame([{'a':1},{'a':1},{'a':1},{'a':1},{'a':1}])
    .pipe(rename_columns, ['b'])
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.set_axis` for this:

```
(pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 5))
 .set_axis(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], axis=1, inplace=False)
 )
```

`inplace` will change in a future version of pandas, but currently defaults to `True`; `axis=1` operates on columns.

Comment: I like this as a domain defined solution for the renaming columns problem. The initial question was also related to find a way to access the attributes of the DataFrame. With `.pipe` I can access the `.dtypes` or the `.describe` methods and add some complex chained functionality.